# TYPO3 10.4.14 increase upload limit

Tags: file-upload, upload, typo3, limit, typo3-10.x

I can't upload files over 2 MB.
I have seen various procedures in various forums, which unfortunately cannot be implemented in TYPO3 10.4.14.

Does anyone know how I can increase the file limit of 2MB?
[image]

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not due to TYPO3 or a setting of TYPO3.

This 2MB limit is the default value for `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in PHP. So you (or your hoster) have to increase this limit to contemporary values.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

---

In former times, there was a setting `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize']` with a default value of 10MB. This setting has been removed in TYPO3 v7.6.0 for keeping TYPO3 in line with PHP settings. (https://forge.typo3.org/issues/71110)